# InvalidOperationException on the second time executing a backgroundworker

Tags: wpf, xml, vb.net, timer, backgroundworker

I'm making an app using wpf and vb.net in vb2010 express and having a problem that is driving me crazy.

I have a timer that execute a backgroundworker every minute:

```
Private Sub timer_Tick() Handles timer.Tick
    If Not bworker.IsBusy Then
        bworker.RunWorkerAsync()
    End If
End Sub
```

The backgroundworker is working with xmlelement and xmldataprovider:

```
Private Sub bworker_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles bworker.DoWork
    Dim source As XmlDataProvider = Application.Current.Resources("r1")
    Dim sometext As String = "something"
    Dim elemento As XmlElement = source.Document.CreateElement("elemento")
    elemento.InnerText = sometext
    e.Result = elemento
End Sub
```

Then I'm using e.Result on RunWorkerComplete to add the XmlElement to source. It works perfect the first time I execute the backgroundworker, but when the timer calls it the second time it throws a InvalidOperationException in the line "elemento.InnerText = sometext" why is that and how can I solve it?

Comment: What is the `Message` of the exception?

Comment: Sorry, it's in spanish, it says "El subproceso que realiza la llamada no puede obtener acceso a este objeto porque el propietario es otro subproceso." that would be something like "The subprocess that is making the call can't obtain access to this object because it belongs to another subprocess".

Comment: sigh... one of the most unfortunate design decisions in .Net: localizing exception messages :-(. That would not be so bad if there was another way to uniquely identify an exception, but there isn't.

Comment: Making some debuggin I realized that the assigment of the value of the string "something" to elemento.InnerText is working so the problem should be something that vb is doing internally...

Comment: It seems that the translation is "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it"

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using `DispatcherTimer` instead of normal `Timer` above?

Comment: I forgot to say that I am actually using the DispatcherTimer, I tried to use the normal Timer and is throwing the same error in a line even before the BackgroundWorker is being called.